# RPM-GPG-KEY Error While Installing Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.1.0)

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, centos7, oracle11gr2

I am Trying to install Oracle Database 11gr2 in CENTOS 7.For installation process I am following this procedure https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/oracle-db-11gr2-installation-on-oracle-linux-7

After downloading and unzipping both the package from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-linx8664soft-100572.html I am running below command to start installing.

```
yum install oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall
```

after processing for few moment I am getting below error.

> warning:
>   /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/ol7_UEKR3/packages/kernel-uek-firmware-3.8.13-118.6.1.el7uek.noarch.rpm:
>   Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY Retrieving key
>   from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
>
> GPG key retrieval failed: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file
>   /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle"

How can I resolve above error and proceed to next step of installation?

Comment: cross-posted on Super User: https://superuser.com/questions/1078438/rpm-gpg-key-error-while-installing-oracle-database-11gr2-on-centos-7

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your system can not verify the GPG-signature of the package because you don't have the corresponding public key. If you trust the package source, you can use:

```
yum install --nogpgcheck oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall
```